# Avalanche magento theme and scp

Tags: magento, themes

We installed the Avalanche Magento Theme, but Simple Configurable products are not working correctly in the Product Display Page.

When we change the value of the drop down for size, the description and other data dioes not change as it does in the default theme.

What will it take to make the Simple Configurable Product to work with the Avalanche magento theme?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am pretty sure someone else already came across this and fixed the problem, by changing some js files, layout files and template files.

Thanks in advance.

**Research:**

For starters, the Avalanche Theme does not use the "Product_addtocart_form" id for the form, but "order-form". This is already a concern regarding standard naming conventions, but I am sure there is a reason for it.

The catalog.xml layout does not load the scp Javascript, so that is one thing that will need loading:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scp_product_extension.js</name></action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built Avalanche. Please change the "order-form" id to "Product_addtocart_form". This will be reverted back in the next update to improve extension compatibility.

**/app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/catalog/product/fd_view-right.phtml**

Line 46

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> onsubmit="return false">
```

Line 69

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
```

**/app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/catalog/ajax/product/view.phtml**

Line 39

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> onsubmit="return false">
```

Line 68

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
```

Line 83

```
$jQ.post('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array()) ?>', $jQ('#product_addtocart_form').serialize(), function(data) {
```

**/app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml**

Line 18

```
productForm : $('product_addtocart_form'),
```

**/skin/frontend/avalanche/default/css/style.css**

Line 371

```
#product_addtocart_form { margin: 10px 0 0 0; padding: 20px 0 0 0; border-top: 1px dashed #545454; }
```

Let me know if this resolves your issue. I'm testing this extension right now on Avalanche and it seems to be loading js/scp_product_extension.js correctly.

Comment: It looks like scp_product_extension.js relies on the markup from the default theme to dynamically update the info. You'll need to edit the JavaScript to fit your needs since Avalanche uses custom markup. Example: Line 231. Update the selector to #product-info-inner h1.

Comment: It would be great if the SCP extension allowed you to specify your own selectors for dynamic updates directly in the config panel for heavily customized themes.

Comment: +1 for going with the default "Magento way" for next release!

Comment: Gave it a quick test, but this will only display the scp correctly to a point, and allow some form of Add to cart, but it will not update the descriptions and images based on the attribute selection, as the description and title is not contained in the form, lines like the following will never work:$$('#product_addtocart_form p.product-image img').each(function(el) {

Comment: Between me, Jim and Jonathan Day, we should get the modified version working, and let you know what needed changing. The scp_product_extension.js will need serious hacking, or the catalog/product/view.phtml needs serious changes.